# Spring Boot app work as standalone but not when Deploy in tomcat 7.X it doesn't work

Tags: spring, tomcat, neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

I am new to Spring boot and recently create an application which use Spring Boot, Neo4j, JSP/Primefaces

When i run it as standalone(With Embeded Tomcat Container, it runs fine and no issue) at this moment packaging is jar

Then i switch it to War packaging and generate war file and deploy to tomcat, it fails with following exception. I am not sure why this error is happening,

tried googling, some days need to provide jdbc url etc in properties file but its neo4j and its url is http:// , which doesnt fit here.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eswaraj.domain.repo.CategoryRepository com.eswaraj.core.service.impl.AppServiceImpl.categoryRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.dataSource()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:142)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:89)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:51)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5456)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.eswaraj.domain.repo.CategoryRepository com.eswaraj.core.service.impl.AppServ     iceImpl.categoryRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryRepository': FactoryBean threw excepti     on on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Injection of autowired depe     ndencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconf     igure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class      path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springfr     amework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedCon     figuration.dataSource()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database ty     pe NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath.
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
     ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested excepti     on is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is      org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.data     Source; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/bo     ot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionS     toreException: Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.dataSource()] threw except     ion; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded data     base please put a supported one on the classpath.
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:151)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1514)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:252)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
     ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exceptio     n is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer     .dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframewo     rk/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefini     tionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.dataSource()] threw e     xception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded      database please put a supported one on the classpath.
```

My Main Config Class Looks like this

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.eswaraj.domain.repo")
@EnableScheduling
@ImportResource({ "classpath:eswaraj-core.xml", "classpath:eswaraj-web-admin-context.xml" })
public class Main extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(new Class[] { Main.class, Initializer.class, XmlResource.class });
    }
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();
        ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "*.jsf", "*.xhtml");
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }

    @ImportResource({ "classpath:eswaraj-core.xml", "classpath:eswaraj-web-admin-context.xml" })
    public static class XmlResource {

    }

    @Bean
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new SpringRestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data");
    }

    @Bean(name = "neo4jTemplate")
    public Neo4jTemplate neo4jTemplate() {
        return new Neo4jTemplate(graphDatabaseService());
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jMappingContext neo4jMappingContext() {
        return new Neo4jMappingContext();
    }

    @Bean
    public JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean transactionManager() throws Exception {
        return new JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean(graphDatabaseService());
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jExceptionTranslator exceptionTranslator() {
        return new Neo4jExceptionTranslator();
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    }

}
```

Application.properties

```
name: Ravi Sharma
server.port:9090
servlet.container.maxThreads:513
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
     <param-name>primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Comment: First your web.xml doesn't do anything and should be removed (in this case it is even dangerous as it turns your app into a servlet 2.5 instead of 3.0 api version). Also make sure you don't have anything in your path that triggers the creation of a datasource (or disable the `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` completely.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for pointing out about web.xml and 3.0 API version... I have removed it. Ofcourse it wudnt solve the issue but its better thing to do.

Comment: Also i removed @EnableAutoConfiguration from my Main.Java, which fixed my problem of tomcat deployment.

Now after this i can deploy this into tomcat and deployment goes fine, but when i access my .xhtml files it displays the content of Xhtml file, without executing them.

It seems registration of facesServlet from Web.xml was working fine but same in my Spring Boot Java Class not working ok

Comment: Don't remove `@EnableAutoConfiguration` as that basically disables Spring Boot.

Comment: I don't know if there is another way of Disabling DataSourceAutoConfiguation except removing @EnableAutoConfiguration

Comment: I strongly suggest a read of the official documentation instead of trying to hack your way trough. The `@EnableAutoConfiguration` has an attribute in which you can specify which config classes to skip.

Answer (score 1):

For me solution was to update to Tomcat 8.
Although  http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war-maven/ says that any servlet container of version 3.0 will do and http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html says that Tomcat version 7 supports it I was unable to launch my war app on it.
But upgrade to Tomcat 8 solved the issue.